# Redirect issue on a firebase hosted site, not on localhost

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router, react-redux, firebase-hosting

I'm using the [este boilerplate](https://github.com/este/este/) for a project using React, Redux and Firebase.
I want a similar functionality to Facebook regarding the root path `'/'`, i.e. you see your news feed on the root path if you are authenticated, but if not, you have to sign in.

More specifically, I want the root path to render `GamesPage` (similar to news feed) if user is authenticated, but if not, then redirect to path `'/signin'`.

The below code works fine on localhost, i.e. if I'm not signed in (authenticated) and go to `localhost:3000/` I immediately redirect to `localhost:3000/signin`. If I however was authenticated, the `GamesPage` is rendered on `localhost:3000/`.

However, for some reason this does not work on our https://[not-the-real-name].firebaseapp.com/, so i'm thinking this is a Firebase problem. What happens there is this error saying:

```
Moved Permanently. Redirecting to /signin
```

[image: Moved Permanently. Redirecting to /signin]

This happens on any path, `'/'`, `'/signin'` (as in picture), etc. and I have no clue why.

---

In my `src/browser/app/App.js` file I have the following lines:

```
      <Match authorized exactly pattern="/" component={GamesPage} />
      <Match pattern="/signin" component={SignInPage} />
      <Match authorized pattern="/users" component={UsersPage} />
      <Match authorized pattern="/me" component={MePage} />
      <Miss component={NotFoundPage} />
      ...
```

Match.js is the same as in este boilerplate: [src/common/app/components/Match.js](https://github.com/este/este/blob/master/src/common/app/components/Match.js)

SignInPage render function begins like this:

```
  render() {
    return (
      this.props.viewer ?
        <Redirect
          to={(
            this.props.location.state &&
            this.props.location.state.from &&
            this.props.location.state.from.pathname
          ) || '/'}
        />
      :
      <View className="sign-in">
      ...
```

I don't know what other code I should add to the question. Any help appreciated.

**EDIT:**
As per request, I've made a live repro, can be seen here: [testeste-690e9.firebaseapp.com](https://testeste-690e9.firebaseapp.com). This is actually the este boilerplate, with only 1 change, I changed `<Match exactly pattern="/" component={HomePage} />` in src/browser/app/App.js to `<Match authorized exactly pattern="/" component={HomePage} />`. There seems to be a problem with having the root authorized.

**EDIT 2:**
`firebase.json` contents:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "./firebase/rules.bolt"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source" : "**/*.@(eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|font.css)",
        "headers" : [{
          "key" : "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
          "value" : "*"
        }]
      }, {
        "source" : "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)",
        "headers" : [{
          "key" : "Cache-Control",
          "value" : "max-age=7200"
        }]
      }
    ],
    "cleanUrls": true,
    "trailingSlash": false
  }
}
```

Comment: This would be a lot easier to debug with a live repro -- maybe create a new dummy Firebase project and deploy it there so folks can take a look?

Comment: Yes, I've made a live repro, can be seen here: https://testeste-690e9.firebaseapp.com/.
This is actually the este boilerplate, with only 1 change, I changed `<Match exactly pattern="/" component={HomePage} />` in `src/browser/app/App.js` to `<Match authorized exactly pattern="/" component={HomePage} />`.
There seems to be a problem with having the root `authorized`.

Comment: Can you also share your `firebase.json` contents?

Comment: @MichaelBleigh Yes, I've edited my post to include `firebase.json`.